# Facebook SDK (android) and API version

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an Android Application that is using Facebook SDK 4.1.0. recently I received an alert from facebook developer claiming that my app was making call to the api Grapsh v2.0.
Some after some research i found out that SDK 4.1-o targets API V.23 ( Actually [i found](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x) that SDk 3.20 hits Api Graph 2.2 so Im at least hitting that version). So how it is possible that I'm getting those warnings? Should I specifically set the Api Graph version in the SDK? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the case where some of the users who does not update the app to the latest version which includes Latest SDK and Latest Graph API.

In this case, the app makes Graph request with lower version and Facebook generate the warning for same.

> To prevent broken experiences for people using your app, we strongly recommend to upgrade your apps to the latest current version at the earliest opportunity.
>   - Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api